# I want to validate time like 6:30 or 11:54 AM but not UTC+6:30

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently using the pattern:

```
(0*[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]) *(AM|am|PM|pm)*
```

But this also validated 6:30 in "UTC+6:30"
I don't want it to validate any time after "UTC+" or "UTC-"

Comment: I have kept this pattern in json file. I am working using C#

Comment: You could use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  - a negative lookbehind, in this case - to say "before my match, there must not be pattern ___". It would look something like `(?<!UTC[+-]) your regex`. This is a comment because I don't know exactly how it would look in C#.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: It works in C#. However, the problem here is, we don't know what kind of string OP is matching this regex against. If OP is validating a field, then add anchors `^` and `$` can be added to the regex instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TesselatingHeckler's idea of using a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is correct, however there is one important thing missing. You also need a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
(?<!UTC[+-])\b(0*[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]) *([AP]M|[ap]m)?
```

Otherwise, `UTC+11:00` would also match (because `1:00` is a valid match for this regex).

Another thing: Why should `00:30` *not* be a valid match? Wouldn't

```
(?<!UTC[+-])\b([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]) *([AP]M|[ap]m)?
```

be better?